# Why a URL cannot open in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, url, uiapplication

I am trying experiment to open a url, the usual way, in a swift app.
But this time it is not working. Maybe my url has something special.

Anyway, this is the URL I tried:

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Hiragana_く_stroke_order_animation.gif
```

And this is the chunk of code I used:

```
    let myURLAdr = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Hiragana_く_stroke_order_animation.gif"

    if let url = URL(string: myURLAdr) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:],
                                  completionHandler: nil)
    } else {print("CANNOT OPEN!!!")}
```

I see:

```
CANNOT OPEN!!!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Or is there any perticular reason why it can't be opened?

Comment: You can't have a Hiragana in a URL. Change the ku to `%E3%81%8F`.

Comment: @Sweeper. Yes. That did it!